# Using pyeda function get the following error

Tags: python-3.4

I'am a beginner on Python and i am studying Boolean Algebra, and i was testing this function:

```
 from pyeda.inter import *

 list(iter_points([z, y, x]))

 [{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1},
 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0},
 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 0, z: 0},
 {x: 1, y: 0, z: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 0},
 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}]
```

i have already install pyeda.

When i execute file I've get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tabela.py", line 3, in 
    list(iter_points[z, y, x])
NameError: name 'z' is not defined

Any one can help me on this issue?

Thanks i lot guys.

BM

Answer (score 1):

PyEDA author here:

Try this instead:

```
>>> from pyeda.inter import *
>>> x, y, z = map(exprvar, 'xyz')
>>> list(iter_points([z, y, x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

print(list(iter_points([z, y, x])))
```

Also remove the x/y/z list you show here.  This is what your result should look like.